# Seeing multiple features from GeoJSON?

Tags: qgis, geojson

In Pablo's answer to [How to open a GeoJSON file with mixed geometries in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/open-a-geojson-file-with-qgis)

He says he 'imported each type at a time' and I do not know how to do that.

I am working with a GeoJSON file that has a mixture of points and polygons, but
points are first, so it only shows points.

How do I get QGIS to show the polygons instead of the points?

Answer (score 1):

If point features are on one end of the page and polygons in the other, open up your geojson in the Notepad, and then cut-paste the polygons feature to a separate text file.

Initial file:

```
var initial = [{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
        [-104.05, 48.99],
        [-97.22,  48.98],
        [-96.58,  45.94],
        [-104.03, 45.94],
        [-104.05, 48.99]
    ]]
   }
  }, {
"type": "Point",
"geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
  }
}];
```

Pulling out the polygon:

```
var polygon = [{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
        [-104.05, 48.99],
        [-97.22,  48.98],
        [-96.58,  45.94],
        [-104.03, 45.94],
        [-104.05, 48.99]
    ]]
   }
  }];
```

Afterwards you'd save it as another geojson file and add it.