# Can I use GeoJSON GeometryCollection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geojson, geometrycollection

I want to create a GeoJSON that contains multiple geometries to be used in QGis later on.
Now I red through the specs here: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#geometrycollection

When I simply copy and paste the GeometryCollection example into a file and add it to QGis nothing shows up.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a QGis Bug?

Comment: You cannot mix different geometry types in a QGIS layer (GeometryCollections =  collection of different Geometries). In the case  of the example, there are 2 layers: a Point layer and a LineString layer

Comment: would be totally fine if QGis recognices them as two layers.. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: yes, with Python in the console

Comment: related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/open-a-geojson-file-with-qgis?rq=1

Comment: Well thinking this way I can also create multiple GeoJSON files instead of a geometry collection. I just thought it is more elegant to use geometry collections instead.

Comment: FeatureCollections work. Not sure about GeometryCollections.

Comment: Great! I'll just use featureCollections instead then.

Comment: A featureCollections is a simple list of geometries. It is different from a GeometryCollection (= a geometry)