# Merging multiple vector layers to one layer with multiple geom types with QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I have a situation where I need to merge a large number of spatial files into a single output with a free tool like QGIS, rather than FME or Alteryx.

Along the lines of this post:
[Merging multiple vector layers to one layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25061/merging-multiple-vector-layers-to-one-layer-using-qgis#)

However, I have some point features, some line features, and some polygon features. This rules out outputs like shapefiles, but anything else is fine like GML, TAB, or a database.

Is there anyway to do this in QGIS?

Every process or model I try makes a shapefile at some point which means this can't work.

Comment: You want to place them in the same database but as separate layers or actually merge together lines, points and polygons?

Comment: I need a single table with a single geometry column (Or a single TAB file would be easier).  No features are to be changed in any way.

Comment: A good point to start is to take a look at [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155870/can-i-use-geojson-geometrycollection-in-qgis). I think you should consider using PostGIS to manage your datasets.

Comment: Do all layers share the same attributes?

Comment: I believe Sqlite or Spatialite will allow multiple feature types (lines, points, polygons) in a single geo enabled table.

Comment: All layers could contain different attributes.  I am trying to find a solution that is GUI based so i can explain easily how to use it to a non technical audience. Currently its so easy with things like Cadcorp Modeller or Alteryx i was hoping to find some equivalent in the Open Source community.  Thanks for all the help guys

Answer (score 7):

You can merge layers with different geometry types together with ogr2ogr.

Here is an example about merging an point shapefile and polygon shapefile into GeoPackage as a new layer "merged" that has a generic geometry type.

```
ogr2ogr -f gpkg merged.gpkg point.shp -nln merged -nlt geometry
ogr2ogr -f gpkg -update -append merged.gpkg polygon.shp -nln merged -nlt geometry

ogrinfo merged.gpkg merged
INFO: Open of `merged.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.

Layer name: merged
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2017-03-31
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 2
Extent: (309.000000, 478.000000) - (599.000000, 604.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
FID Column = fid
Geometry Column = geom
attr: String (1.0)
OGRFeature(merged):1
  attr (String) = B
  POINT (382 478)

OGRFeature(merged):2
  attr (String) = A
  POLYGON ((309 584,599 604,466 493,309 584))
```

However, you will have some problems with QGIS with using that layer because QGIS can't handle points, lines, and polygons on a same layer. QGIS requires that layer is split by the geometry type

[image]

You can open the merged layer as a single layer with OpenJUMP.