# Recommended utility for editing of GEOJSON files

Tags: geojson, tools

I have a geojson file with the boundaries and some very basic statistics (population) for all the counties in US. States are enumerated (1,2,...), not named.

I also have a csv file with a comprehensive demographic and health statistics for each county (county is a row, statistics are columns).

I would like to add these values from the csv file as properties, for the county.

Is there a good, open source tool you would recommend for doing this programmatically, and in bulk.
I was looking into Python's [geojson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geojson).

Answer (score 5):

It might be easiest to try using [QGIS and dropping the geojson into it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/how-to-open-a-geojson-file-with-mixed-geometries-in-qgis). Then do a [join by attribute](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html).

A side benefit of it being graphical is that you can browse/label the counties and then quite easily spot check your joined data.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not Python based, you should better use [geojson-join](https://github.com/tmcw/geojson-join) package.

It works for JSON, CSV or DBF and it uses the command line. No need to code here except if you have a particular purpose I'm unaware.