# QGIS does not show the Geometry Collection Polygons from JSON file

Tags: qgis, json

I'm trying to import a JSON file I got from a customer and convert it to a shapefile.  The JSON file appears to have two Geometry types (Polygon and GeometryCollection).  I can get the Polygons to import properly, however I cannot seem to get the GeometryCollection to import the Polygons they have in them.  I am running QGIS 2.18.7 which I believe can handle multiple types.

I've stored the file I am trying to import here:
[Sample File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3oZAe8v-JSxTUlTc1VEQmFmam8/view?usp=sharing)

Is the file corrrupt or am I missing something?

Comment: OpenJUMP can import geojson with geometrycollections. You can then explode the collections and split the layer by geometry types for saving data into shapefiles.

Comment: I gave OpenJUMP a shot.  However it is giving me errors trying to open the geometry collections as well.

Comment: Spatialite supports GeometryCollections if you want to keep the collection intact.

Answer (score 9):

The file is not corrupt. QGIS does not support `GeometryCollection` as a valid geometry type. You will have to parse it. Here is a related [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/30433/52152). Something like this will get you to the data:

```
with open(json_file, 'r') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    for feature in data['features']:
        for geometry in feature['geometry']['geometries']:
            if geometry['type'] == "Polygon":
                polygon = geometry['coordinates']
```

Comment: According to the QGIS import dialog, there are 3 polygons and 16 Geometry Collections.  You are correct if you look at the first ones, the Geometry Collections have a polygon and a point.  However if you go to the end of the file, you will find the 3 plain polygon items.  QGIS will load those three, I just can't get it to properly load the other 16.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are right with OpenJUMP, the GeoJSON driver seems to have a bug. You can use ogr2ogr for converting the data into JML format and do the rest with OpenJUMP.

```
ogr2ogr -f jml tommy.jml tommy.json
```

**EDIT** *OpenJUMP can open GeoJSON with GeometryCollections directly since revision r5436. Download snapshot from https://sourceforge.net/projects/jump-pilot/files/OpenJUMP_snapshots/.*

Open the JML (or GeoJSON if you have version r5436 or above) that contains polygons and GeometryCollections with OpenJUMP.

[image]

Find the Extract Layers by Geometry Type tool.

[image]

Select options for extracting geometries for shapefiles and exploding GeometryCollections.

[image]

The tool will create two layers, one for points and another for polygons. Save them into shapefiles and you have done it.

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  Only thing I had to research was how to run the org2org command.  Never used the "OSGeo4W Shell" Under the QGIS program list before, so had to find it.  Thanks for your help.