# Merging layers with different geometry (PointZ and MultiLineStringZ) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, merge

I try to merge two different layers but they don't have the same geometry, as i said one layer is Point and the other Line.

Is it possible to merging them in one layer?

Comment: Do you want to store data with different geometry in one file or have the data displayed in QGIS as one layer?

Comment: I want to displayed them as one layer in qgis ?

Comment: Do layers have exactly same attributes (same names, same data types)?

Comment: they have different atributes

Comment: One layer has one fixed set of attributes. Do want that the combined layer will have attributes from both layers (a.attr1, a.attr2, a.attr3, b.attr1, b.attr2, b.attr3...). Naturally half of the attributes would be NULL then.

Comment: Based on what you intend to do, a workaround would be creating a (very small) buffer around points as well as lines - then both (technically) will be polygons, whereas the "look and feel" still is more or less of "point" and "line". But this really is "quick and dirty".

Answer (score 4):

**No**, because *"QGIS does not support `GeometryCollection` as a valid geometry type."*

You can not merge layers with ["Merge vector layers"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#merge-vector-layers), but you can package them with ["Package layers"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/database.html#package-layers).

As a workaround, you may try to create a GeoJSON file with mixed geometries in it.

---

**References:**

- [QGIS does not show the Geometry Collection Polygons from JSON file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238354/qgis-does-not-show-the-geometry-collection-polygons-from-json-file)
- [Opening GeoJSON file with mixed geometries in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/opening-geojson-file-with-mixed-geometries-in-qgis)

Comment: Can user create such GeoJSON with QGIS?

Comment: IMHO, it is possible but will probably require some Python/PyQGIS. *disclaimer:* never did it before.